# How to get the hostname of a service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I need the hostname of the service lensespostgres-postgresql, but I get an error:

```
$ kubectl get services -n default                                                                                              
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                           ClusterIP   ........     <none>        443/TCP    20m
lensespostgres-postgresql            ClusterIP   ........     <none>        5432/TCP   14m
lensespostgres-postgresql-headless   ClusterIP   None         <none>        5432/TCP   14m
$ ping lensespostgres-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local
ping: lensespostgres-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known
```

Why?

Comment: You can't ping an address containing "http://". ~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=11.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=11.7 ms
^C
~$ ping [http://8.8.8.8](http://8.8.8.8)
ping:  [http://8.8.8.8](http://8.8.8.8): Name or service not known

Comment: @sarlacii I get the same error without http://

Comment: kubectl get svc clusterip

Comment: @sarlacii I get: Error from server (NotFound): services "xx.xx.xx.xx" not found

Comment: Hmm, that's beyond me... what do you get if you check the pod: kubectl get pod -o wide, and also with --all-namespaces to list all pods in all namespaces?

Comment: @sarlacii$ I get this: kubectl get pod lensespostgres-postgresql-0 -o wide
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP         NODE                                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
lensespostgres-postgresql-0   1/1     Running   0          49m   xx.xx.xx.xx  gke-cluster-1-default-pool-xxxxxxxx   <none>           <none>

Comment: Are you running these commands from a `kubectl run` debugging shell inside the cluster, or somewhere else?  You can't access ClusterIP-type services from outside the cluster; even a shell on one of the cluster nodes is still "outside".

Comment: Howdy there, given that this is tagged gke I presume it's being run on Google Cloud Platform, correct?  
With that assumption in mind, I also presume that, given that you are calling your services, you've already connected to the gke group you have running using `gcloud container clusters get-credentials <YOUR_CLUSTER --zone <YOUR_ZONE> --project <YOUR_PROJECT_ID>`.  
Assuming both of those things I'd like to ask you what the infrastructure you have set up is and what settings you used when creating the cluster.  
PS: it ought to be `kubectl get svc <SERVICE_NAME>`, not `clusterip`

Comment: @DavidMaze I am inside the cluster on GCP

Comment: @fabc yes, both assumptions are correct. I have just created a simple cluster with 2 nodes and installed postgresql with helm.

Comment: @fabc $ kubectl get svc lensespostgres-postgresql
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
lensespostgres-postgresql   ClusterIP   xx.xx.xx.xx    <none>        5432/TCP   2m3s

Comment: Ok... I've been trying to reproduce your issue, and I've found that, in my case I was just being silly. I haven't been able to reproduce the issue, but that was because I'd initially attempted to ping/wget the instances both with the private IP and from without the IP ranges allowed by the pre-formed gke firewall rules. Which you can see on the VPC network you've created the cluster on. I believe the default is, funnily enough, called "default". The rules generally restrict the nodes within a pod to "talk" to eachother, so any calls from outside the range are ignored. [Continued]

Comment: [Continued] So if you have those initial restrictions you'd have to either remove them (to be able to contact them via their EXTERNAL IP, which you can find under the network interface details) or port forward the endpoint under "Services and Ingress", if you've not done so already. If you have done so already, I would recommend trying to contact that port specifically, as the ping command most likely will not connect to the port specified because it uses ICMP. [The example provided on gke](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/deploying-highly-available-postgresql-with-gke) uses a 5000 port.

Answer (score 1):

To get the hostname of the service you need dnsutils

If dnsutils is not installed please follow the below steps

```
   sudo apt-get install dnsutils
   sudo apt-get update
```

Create the yaml file for dnsutils as mentioned in the [link](https://dev.to/vepo/finding-dns-for-kubernetes-service-3p0e)

Apply the created yaml file using  the below command

```
kubectl apply -f dnsutils.yaml
```

To get the hostname of the service use the below command:

```
kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- nslookup <service-name>
```

For the further information of yaml file and steps you can refer this [link](https://dev.to/vepo/finding-dns-for-kubernetes-service-3p0e)

I have tried this in my project and it worked for me